# How to see the actual number of CPUs a script used?

Tags: slurm

I want to know how many of the reserved CPUs the executed script actually used so that I could optimize CPU reservation (not to over reserve CPUs)
 
For example if I have executed the script with limits like
 `srun -t 60 -c 4 --mem=10000 SOMECOMMAND`
After the job is finished I can get the stats of the job with e.g 
  `sacct -l -j JOBNR`
From these statistics I see memory consumption of the job from  "MaxRSS" but I can't figure out how to see the number of CPUs used? 
The "AllocCPUS" and requested CPUs "ReqTres" are always the same. I understand CPUTime gives me Elapsed time * CPU but this seems always to be AllocCPUS * Elapsed time.
Did I miss some field or have all my jobs actually used all the CPUs or this is not shown by slurm at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field you are looking for is `TotalCPU`. From the `sacct` manpage:

> TotalCPU  The  sum  of  the SystemCPU and UserCPU time used by the job or job step.

Divide this by the `CPUTime` to get the efficiency.

> CPUTime   Formatted (Elapsed time * CPU) count used by a job or step.

Slurm comes with a Perl script to compute the efficiency of a job named `seff` (in the 'contrib' section). See [here](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/blob/master/contribs/seff/seff).